# Weird movement / rotation of Unity editor scene view camera

Tags: unity

I am using the Unity 2017.3.0f3 Personal (64) bit editor for Pc, Mac and Linux Standalone (DX11 on DX10 GPU). I was editing my terrain when suddenly my camera for moving around in the editor went absolute wack.

The camera now rotates around any object I click on and pretty much doesn't work at all. I cannot move using the WASD keys anymore.

I have never had this problem before so I believe I just accidentally clicked the wrong button. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: This doesn't give much to go on - what is rotating? A mesh? the camera view? Also you mention a "similar problem" - similar to what? Without some context, there's not enough information given to provide much help.

Comment: I am sorry this was very vauge. The camera view is rotating around any object  I click. I cannot move with the wasd keys anymore and when I scroll in too close everything disappears even though I am not under the world. The only way I can move is with the scroll wheel.

Comment: That additional info is a good start. It also would really help if you included which editor you were using - either as a tag or also in the question directly.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was using the Unity 2017.3.0f3 Personal (64) bit editor for Pc, Mac and Linux Standalone <DX11 on DX10 GPU>. I have never had this problem before so I believe I just accidentally clicked the wrong button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Unity dev, but a causal search of the [navigation documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html) suggests you might need to click the Scene Gizmo to get back to a Perspective view.

The Scene Gizmo looks like a square with cones pointing to the faces (aligned on the XYZ axes) & looks like this:

[image: Unity Scene Gizmo]

Comment: Just to be clear: you wanna click **the padlock** in the gizmo (upper right in your picture)

Answer (score 0):

On your scene, under the square with cones around it and the letters y and x, under that there is a thing that will say iso. click that.

Comment: This seems to be effectively the same advice that Pikalek shared two years ago. Is there any new information you'd like to add with your answer, like maybe a screenshot indicating the relevant control, or an explanation of what this setting does and why the camera behaves as described in the question?

Comment: @DMGregory It did draw my attention to the fact that my answer could have been more descriptive in terms of describing the scene gizmo.